# Why do I need an the event loop in gevent?

Tags: python, gevent

This is the official introduction for [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/). After reading it, I still have no idea what is gevent. It looks like gevent is a collection of :

- Fast event loop based on libev or libuv.
- Lightweight execution units based on greenlets.
- API that re-uses concepts from the Python standard library (for examples there are events and queues).
- Cooperative sockets with SSL support
- Cooperative DNS queries performed through a threadpool, dnspython, or c-ares.
- Monkey patching utility to get 3rd party modules to become cooperative
- TCP/UDP/HTTP servers
- Subprocess support (through gevent.subprocess)
- Thread pools

I never heard of things about event loop in javascript. Event and message is implemented as function call. There is no loop. 
while (true) {} is wrong period.

My question is: **What is event loop in the gevent? Why do I need it?**

Comment: The event loop in javascript is handled by the browser. Does not mean it is not here, just it is not directly accessible from js.

Comment: Just to make that clear: the google search "javascript event loop" show an 8 digit number of found results. Yes, Javascript *implementations* use event loops, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

event loop is how every asynchronous event system works. There is a loop, checking for events and waiting for things to happen. When something happens, it **deals with event** - that is it will call some code and when that code is over, returns to the loop.

There is no magical way to call your code when something happens - you need a loop checking for conditions and calling the correct code. Frequently the loop is hidden inside the library/framework but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.